# Optimize rendering a map w/ large data set

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, optimization, data-visualization

I'm currently rendering a US map along with every district's border. The grabbing the features of the topojson, we have an array of ~13,000 rows.

I'm also joining data to the topojson file, and running through a csv of ~180,000 rows. I believe I've optimized this process of joining data by ID enough using memoization, where the CSV is essentially turned into a hash, and each ID is the key to it's row data.

This process^ is run 24 times in Next JS through SSG to further the user experience, and so all 24 versions of this map is calculated before the first visit of this deployment. I'm sadly timing out during deployment phase for this specific web page^.

I've inspected the program and seem to find that painting/filling each district may be what's causing the slowdown. Are there any tips you all use to optimize rendering an SVG map of many path elements? Currently the attributes to this map:

1: tooltip for each district styled in tailwind

2: around 5 properties turned to text from topojson file w/ joined data to display upon hover, displayed by tooltip

3: filled dynamically with this snippet which runs a function based on the district's property `type`

`.attr('fill', function (d) {return figureOutColor(d['properties'].type);})`

4: adding a mouseover, mousemove, and mouseout event handler to each district.

Edit: Code snippet of adding attrs to my map

```
export const drawMap = (svgRef: SVGSVGElement, allDistricts: any[]) => {
  const svg = d3.select(svgRef);
  svg.selectAll('*').remove();
  const projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa().scale(900).translate([400, 255]);
  const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

  const tooltip = d3
    .select('body')
    .append('div')
    .attr(
      'class',
      'absolute z-10 invisible bg-white',
    );
  svg
    .selectAll('.district')
    .data(allDistricts)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'district stroke-current stroke-0.5')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('fill', function (d) {
      return figureOutColor(d['properties'].type);
    })
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
      return tooltip
        .style('visibility', 'visible')
        .text(`${d.properties.name});
    })
    .on('mousemove', function (data) {
      return tooltip.style('top', d3.event.pageY - 40 + 'px').style('left', d3.event.pageX + 'px');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d) {
      d3.select(this).classed('selected fill-current text-white', false);
      return tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
```

Comment: There are ways to do items 1-4 well and poorly.  If you are doing them poorly I would suggest doing them well.  However I can't tell without the code.  Are you able to increase the timeout you are running into?

Comment: Will edit post w/ more code snippets. Vercel seems to have a more forgiving limitation of 25 seconds as opposed to 5 via a plan upgrade. I'm weighing out if that needs to be done, if the data should be less accurate by aggregating 13,000 districts into 50 states instead(this loaded fine w/ no issues at all, but the data reflected isn't quite accurate to what I want) @James

Comment: @James added my map drawing function